# How to know when spinach has gone bad?

Tags: refrigerator, spinach

I just opened up a fresh pack of spinach which is two days until its use by date.  It had been stored in the fridge at perhaps 6c since yesterday.

I noticed that some leaves have little brown dots on them in the middle and on the edges. Some leaves are also slightly torn in places.  The browning is a bit like what you see in this image:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-tell-when-spinach-has-gone-bad

Are these brown dots/tears a sign of spinach gone bad or can I eat it(including the brown bits)?

Why did it develop if it is in use by date and had been refrigerated?

The quora answerer says you can rip any 'damaged' parts and eat it however since some parts of it are damaged isn't it safer to just discard everything?

Again are these parts really damaged because it seems in date and refrigerated to me. Just those brown dots on a number of leaves are making me uncomfortable.  If I were to remove the brown parts, cook it and use the cooked spinach the next day, isn't it lkely to have developed more problems in which case one should use it same day?

Is there anything else I can look for e.g. bad smell which I don't notice btw?

Comment: Pictures, please...!

Comment: it's in the link stephie.

Comment: In the photo, I see more than just little spots.  I see some leaf pieces that have gone entirely slimy.

Comment: The link is *apparently* someone else's - "a bit like"

Comment: I grow my own spinach, and sometimes these spots appear in the spoace of a day. Sometimes they are due to leaf demage, sometimes no reason I can determine. I tear off the damaged spots, thoroughly wash the remainder, and use it. If, however, there is ANY sliminess in the spinach, I discard the whole batch (on the advice of my Oma years ago).